# Update language of a form which is closed

Tags: c#

currently I am working on a simple multi-language application. This application have two forms:

Form 1: Select Language (English & Italian)

Form 2: Welcome message

Form1.cs

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                Assembly a = Assembly.Load("LanguageManagement");
                ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("LanguageManagement.Language.English", a);

                Class1 lang = new Class1();
                lang.Language(rm);
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Assembly a = Assembly.Load("LanguageManagement");
                ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("LanguageManagement.Language.Italian", a);

                Class1 lang = new Class1();
                lang.Language(rm);
            }
    }
```

When the user press button1 (English), the English resource manager is used and Class 1 is called.

```
class Class1
    {
        public void Language(ResourceManager rm)
        {
            Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            form1.label1.Text = rm.GetString("_Name");
            form1.label2.Text = rm.GetString("_Surname");
            form1.label3.Text = rm.GetString("_Age");
            form1.button4.Text = rm.GetString("_Enter");

            //Form2 form = new Form2();
            Form2 form = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];

            form.label1.Text = rm.GetString("_Welcome");
        }
    }
```

If the user does not open Form2 before choosing the language the following error is displayed:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in LanguageManagement.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

How can I update the language of form2, even if it is never opened?

Thanks :)

Comment: Using the debugger, which variable or field is null?

Comment: If `Form2` is not open can you not open it, then set the welcome message.

Comment: I need to update all text of the 2 forms... even if form2 is never opened.

Comment: where in your code do you want to display the Form2 actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it seems that you would like to use `Class1` as a filling agent. You could make the method `static` (since it is not using any class variables) and pass in addition the forms into it to be filled:

```
public void Language(ResourceManager rm, Form1 form1, Form2 form2)
{
    // FORM 1
    form1.label1.Text = rm.GetString("_Name");
    form1.label2.Text = rm.GetString("_Surname");
    form1.label3.Text = rm.GetString("_Age");
    form1.button4.Text = rm.GetString("_Enter");

    // FORM 2
    form2.label1.Text = rm.GetString("_Welcome");
}
```

you should instantiate a `Form2` object on the class level in `Form1` and pass both variables into the method:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load("LanguageManagement");
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("LanguageManagement.Language.English", a);

    // here both forms will be filled
    Class1.Language(rm, this, form2);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load("LanguageManagement");
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("LanguageManagement.Language.Italian", a);

    Class1.Language(rm, this, form2);
}
```

you can simplify your code because both button presses have a lot in common:

```
private void FillWithLanguage(string language)
{
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load("LanguageManagement");
    ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(language, a);

    // here both forms will be filled
    Class1.Language(rm, this, form2);
}
```

now you can reduce you button code to this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillWithLanguageResourceManager("LanguageManagement.Language.English");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillWithLanguageResourceManager("LanguageManagement.Language.Italian");    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I wanted. Sorry if I did not express myself very good in the beginning.

Comment: @Draco0013 you are welcome. and Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Draco0013 You can simplify your code a little (avoid double code) I made an edit to my post. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `static` member that saves the `ResourceManager` and is accessible from everywhere. When `Form2` opens, it can simply look at the `static` member and change the language by itself.

```
class Class1
{
    public static ResourceManager Resources { get; private set; }

    public void Language(ResourceManager rm)
    {
        Resources = rm;

        Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
        form1.label1.Text = rm.GetString("_Name");
        form1.label2.Text = rm.GetString("_Surname");
        form1.label3.Text = rm.GetString("_Age");
        form1.button4.Text = rm.GetString("_Enter");

        //Form2 form = new Form2();
        Form2 form = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
    }
}
```

In your `Form2`:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    form.label1.Text = Form1.Resources.GetString("_Welcome");
}
```